# array shows only last $_post value

Tags: php, arrays, session

I want to create simple shopping cart for learning. The problem is that I've tried many of them but none of the samples could not add to my existing project.

Let's see some code:

index.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
//shopping cart
if(isset($_POST['tocart']))
{
$pid = intval($_POST['product_id']);
$cart = new Cart();
$cart -> AddToCart($pid);
}
?>
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="form1"> 
              <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="12" />
              <input type="hidden" name="tocart" value="tocart" />
              <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
              <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add the product</button> </form>
```

model.php

```
class Cart
{
    function AddToCart($pid)
     {

     if(isset($_SESSION['prod_count']))
         {
           $_SESSION['prod_count']++;
           $incart=$_SESSION['prod_count'];
           $_SESSION[$incart]['product_id'] = $pid;
         }
         else 
         {
           $_SESSION['prod_count'] = 0;
           $incart=$_SESSION['prod_count'];
           $_SESSION[$incart]['product_id'] = $pid;
         }
      }

}
```

Cart.php

```
<?php 
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

when I add 4 products it shows:

Array(2) { ["prod_count"]=> &int(4) [4]=> array(1) { ["product_id"]=> int(12) } }

Shouldn't it be something like:

```
Array(2) { ["prod_count"]=> &int(1) [1]=> array(1) { ["product_id"]=> int(15)}
           ["prod_count"]=> &int(2) [2]=> array(1) { ["product_id"]=> int(14)}
           ["prod_count"]=> &int(3) [3]=> array(1) { ["product_id"]=> int(17)}
           ["prod_count"]=> &int(4) [4]=> array(1) { ["product_id"]=> int(12) } }
```

Comment: Did you try using another key first (so resulting in a multidimensional array) like `$_SESSION['items'][ $incart ]['product_id'] = $pid`?

Comment: You override your data (prod_count, ...) each time you add a product.

Comment: any idea how to fix it?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$_SESSION[]['product_id'] = $pid;
```

by having just [] it will create a new array instance.

==========
Edit in response to commment.

How about try;

```
$_SESSION['products'][]['product_id'] = $pid;
```

So you are defining it in a sub-array and not directly on the top level session object.

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["product_id"]=> int(12) } } last product info shows up only